# Downloaded Excel File cannot be open properly using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

In my project, I make exporting data to excel 2007 using PhpExcel 1.8.0.
I tried it as the followings code.

Excel File is saved in Client side but when I open the downloaded Excel file, I get the warning message "**We found a problem with some content in 'filename.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.**"

Could anyone help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!!!

```
$_read_sheet = EXCEL_SHEET_PATH . "template.xlsx";
$ym_dirname = date("Y") . '_' . date("m");
$output_file_name = "MyFile_" . date("YmdHis", time());
$output_file = $output_file_name . ".xlsx";
$output_file = mb_convert_encoding($output_file, "SJIS", "UTF-8");
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$xl = $reader->load("$_read_sheet");
$xl->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $xl->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue("AV3", date("Y/m/d"));
// redirect output to client browser
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$output_file.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xl, 'Excel2007');
// Write file to the browser
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Comment: You should read 4.6.3 Write a date or time into a cell in PHPExcel docs - http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/119187

Comment: Open the file in a text editor. Look for any leading/trailing whitespace characters at the beginning or end of the file; look for a BOM header at the beginning of the file; look for any plaintext PHP error messages or any HTML markup in the file.... if your script is generating any output at all, it will corrupt an Excel file saved to `php://output`